# Is that normal behavior for unicode supported db (UTF-8) or it's bug?

Tags: h2

I am using 1.4.197 H2 in memory db and have the varchar match issue with national character (İ - uppercase, i - lowercase). After some research I got some test sql dual test for easy explanation of problem.
Is that normal result for the below request:

```
select lower('İ') as lower_from_upper,
    STRINGTOUTF8 (lower('İ')) as lower_from_upper_utf,
    lower('i') as lower_from_lower,
    STRINGTOUTF8 (lower('i')) as lower_from_lower_utf
from dual;
```

Result:

| lower_from_upper | lower_from_upper_utf | lower_from_lower | lower_from_lower_utf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i̇ | 69cc87 | i | 69 |

For the first look they seems as same characters in output, but unicode columns give different values for them.

That is all, thanks in advance!

Comment: Congratulations, you've just learned of the turkish-i problems. It *basically* means that any function that changes case has to be locale-specific. If there's no clear mechanism to specify which locale to apply, then that's probably a bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Actually there is no such mechanism to specify locale at sql level for h2. I think it's possible to detect and replace this letter at application level, but it's not smart decision I think.

Comment: lower_from_upper seems to be the "normal" latin `i` followed by U+0307, the combining dot above. I honestly don't understand how that makes any sense in *any* locale, as `i` already has a dot above it. The only way I could understand it if your input was already `I` with a combining dot above *and* the locale simply transformed the dotless `I` to `i` and ignored the combining mark, but the select statement you post doesn't use the two-codepoint variant of `İ` but uses U+0130 instead.

Comment: Its very strange, but searh engine return the results for 'cahi' and 'CAHİ' form DB, but if I write 'CAHİD' it gives results, but 'cahid' NOT! So problem not in 'İ' letter itself, when it followed by 'D' or 'd' it fails. The actual string in DB is CAHİD, and of course lower case applied to column and keyword both, plus %keyword% at DB sql level.

Comment: I don't know how much H2 does for you there, but do you do any normalization? Something like applying NFC to both all stored data *and* the search terms?

Comment: @JoachimSauer No my input was not 'I' (such letter also exist in azeri latin chars and the lower case of it is 'ı')

Comment: @JoachimSauer I use spring framework with java and both client server support unicode absolutelly. I only incase % char to the keyword and all other stuff, like lowercase is in SQL. I tried using direct sql request without application through native H2 SQL panel, it fails for my case.